# Polymorphic deserialization with Jackson using abstract types in Ktor

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialise a JSON string and have issues with one of the properties that is supposed to be mapped in one of the enums that implement a common interface as follows.

```
{
  "position": "OFFICE_MANAGER"
}
```

```kotlin
class Employee(
  @JsonProperty("position") 
  val position: EmployeePosition
)

interface EmployeePosition

enum class EmployeePositionBusiness: EmployeePosition {
  BI;
}

enum class EmployeePositionLeadership: EmployeePosition {
  PROJECT_MANAGER, OFFICE_MANAGER
}
```

I keep on getting the following error:
`abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information.`

**Edit: Solution**

```kotlin
@JsonDeserialize(using = EmployeePositionDeserializer::class)
interface EmployeePosition

enum class EmployeePositionBusiness: EmployeePosition {
  BI;
}

enum class EmployeePositionLeadership: EmployeePosition {
  PROJECT_MANAGER, OFFICE_MANAGER
}

class EmployeePositionDeserializer(vc: Class<*>? = null) : StdDeserializer<EmployeePosition>(vc) {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): EmployeePosition =
        when (val position = p.valueAsString) {
            in EmployeePositionBusiness.enumValues() -> EmployeePositionBusiness.enumValueOf(position)
            in EmployeePositionLeadership.enumValues() -> EmployeePositionLeadership.enumValueOf(position)
            else -> throw Exception("Could not parse position $position")
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a complete error message, including a stack trace.  That first bit of stuff isn't valid JSON.  Are you using a JSON parser that has a special case to allow dictionary keys to be unquoted?  Wouldn't you want `@JsonProperty("position")` to match the code to that particular data blob?

Comment: What exactly is your question? The error message is pretty clear about the available options for solving this problem.

Comment: My issue is that I've tried following the suggestions and was not able to make it work. I updated my answer to include what I have already tried.